# Jdatechooser getDate() method is not working

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I'm trying to get date from `jDateChooser`. So I used this update query. But now I'm getting this `getDate()` method as `cannot find the symbol` error. I'm using JDBC class. And following  is my query:

```
try { 
        new JDBC().putData("UPDATE work SET balance='"+txtValue.getText()+"', date='"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date.getdate()) +"' WHERE id='1'");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() +" "+e);
    }
```

Comment: I can think of any number problems...How is `date` declared?  Is it being shadowed by another local variable of a different type?

Comment: date is the column name in table and data type is DATETIME

Comment: Sorry, how is the `date` object declared?  Is it actually a `JDateChooser`?  Is it shadowed by another local variable of a different type?

Comment: if you are talking about this. date.getdate() it is equal dateChooserCombo1.getDate()

Comment: @Alex I tryed it. But same result I don't get getDate() as a valid method.

Comment: Alright I'm confused, you say `date.getdate` is equal to `dateChooserCombo1.getDate()`, which I would assume then `date` is actually a `java.util.Date` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have error here:

```
date.getdate()
```

It should be capital `D`

```
date.getDate()
```

Comment: I used jDateChooser not dateChooserCombo and now that method is working. I don't know why. But thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

try this with JCalendar 1.4
---------------------------------`((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this for latest version.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getSelectedDate().getTime());
```

Comment: this worked for me 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());